# Comma needed in 30-day, money-back guarantee?

Tags: punctuation

Is a comma needed in the phrases '30-day, money-back guarantee' and '90-day, no-risk trial'?

If so, why? If not, why not?

I see them written both ways -- that is, with and without the comma -- but certainly one way has to be more correct than the other way.

Thanks for any feedback.

Comment: @medica Oopsies. Somehow I managed to miss that very obvious duplicate before answering. I’d say the questions should be merged or the other should be made a duplicate of this one (rather than vice versa), since this one gives more detail and is a better question than the other one.